# PYTHONPATH - dynamic for different python installs?

Tags: python, pythonpath

On my CentOS5 server, I have both Python2.4 and 2.6 (2.4 is required for yum to work). I'm not sure what happened, but suddenly the system gets very confused every time I try to run a file whose modules are loaded into the 2.4 site-packages directory. I checked the PYTHONPATH/sys.path and it looks like everything was overwritten with 2.6 environment data instead.

It didn't used to do this. I simply declared /usr/bin/python or /usr/bin/python26 in the shebang statement at the beginning of the script and it always found the correct modules just fine.

Is there a way for the PYTHONPATH variable to be dynamic and load different paths based on which python interpreter is running?

Otherwise I'm going to have to manually edit the path in every application, which seems like overkill.

It started after installing web.py (which I love, by the way).

Traceback: 
As someone commented below, I changed the shebang to be #!/usr/bin/env python for this program:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/linkchecker", line 24, in ?
    import codecs
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/codecs.py", line 268
    return (b"", 0)
              ^
```

Another example, trying to use yum:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/yum", line 5, in ?
    import yum
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/yum/__init__.py", line 21, in ?
    import os
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/os.py", line 758
    bs = b""
           ^
```

I've noticed a couple programs not confounded by the b"" syntax, and all of them are programs meant to use 2.4 that are for some reason using 2.6. If I try to make the program use the 2.6 interpreter it is able to understand that syntax, but then can't find any of the other modules (which are in the 2.4 site-packages directory).

I don't know what that syntax is, as they were written into modules which I got from sourceforge, however they were working last week. I am not sure what changed.

Thanks,
Tom

Answer (score 2):

First of all, use virtualenv to isolate packages for multiple Python installations. Most of your problems will go away immediately.

Second, as Ibp has recommended in his answer, change the shebang line to use the "currently active" python binary so that it will work across multiple interpreters.

Comment: I am not familiar with virtualenv. I'll look into that.

Comment: Yes, I did the easy_install for 2.6; trying to figure out how to get it into 2.4 also. (I'm assuming I need it for both installs, no?). 2.4  HAS easy_install, but once again this has been overwritten by the 2.6 conundrum. I tried specifying the installation directory, but that just put the 2.6 egg into the 2.4 directory.

Comment: At this point, I'm tempted to get rid of both installs and start over from scratch to untangle this.

Comment: Install both the Pythons using your system package manager and then create 2 virtualenvs (using the `-p` switch to specify the interpreter). `pip install` whatever you want into these virtualenvs rather than the system package directories.

Comment: Sadly, I can't install anything using the system's package manager, as it's reliant on Python2.4. /grin

Comment: I've never liked CentOS5 all that much anyway. I'm migrating to a different linux distro that doesn't require python2.4.

Comment: Then install the system python in the system directories, manually compile and install the other python in `/opt` and then create separate virtualenvs to keep packages.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the shebang (first bytes of the file)

```
#!/usr/bin/python
```

use the shebang

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

Edit: I second Noufal's suggestion to use virtualenv.

Comment: I made the change as you suggested, and changed the program in question (this time) to use /usr/bin/env python, however it is still using the 2.6 modules. Added tracebacks above. Tried with a program native to the server (yum) as well.